# Maximum pool size when using ThreadPool Python

Tags: python, threadpool

I am using ThreadPool to achieve multiprocessing. When using multiprocessing, pool size limit should be equivalent to number of CPU cores. 
My question- When using ThreadPool, should the pool size limit be number of CPU cores?

This is my code

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
class Subject():
    def __init__(self, url):
       #rest of the code
   def func1(self):
      #returns something
if __name__=="__main__":
   pool_size= 11
   pool= Pool(pool_size)
   objects= [Subject() for url in all_my_urls]
   for obj in objects:
     pool.apply_async(obj.func1, ())
   pool.close()
   pool.join()
```

What should be the maximum pool size be? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use threads for multiprocessing, you can only achieve multithreading. Multiple threads cannot run concurrently in a single Python process because of the GIL and so multithreading is only useful if they are running IO heavy work (e.g. talking to the Internet) where they spend a lot of time waiting, rather than CPU heavy work (e.g. maths) which constantly occupies a core.

So if you have many IO heavy tasks running at once then having that many threads will be useful, even if it's more than the the number of CPU cores. A very large number threads will eventually have a negative impact on performance, but until you actually measure a problem don't worry. Something like 100 threads should be fine.

Comment: OP is already using the `multiprocessing` module, which just imitates `multithreading`.

Comment: The `ThreadPool` in `multiprocessing` is not really multiprocessing, it's just there to match the API of the usual `Pool` which uses actual processes.

Comment: I think you are right (+1). It seems to be undocumented and I confused it with just `Pool`.

Comment: Sorry for a lazy argument

Comment: @PranitiGupta Yes it is, I was mistaken.

Comment: If func1() runs a command every x sec (doesn't terminate until keyboard interruption provided) and if I want to run this function for different objects in parallel, what is the best choice-> multiprocessing or ThreadPool? I am still confused regarding ThreadPool. Does it create a pool of threads or pool of processes?

Comment: @PranitiGupta a ThreadPool is a pool of threads, as one would expect. The only unexpected thing in terms of names is that it is found in the `multiprocessing` module. If you are using `time.sleep(1)` between calls to the command, then one thread will be able to work while the other is sleeping, but if they all sleep at the same time and work at the same time, multiple threads may not help.

Comment: @AlexHall They all should sleep at the same time. I guess ThreadPool is not the solution. Can you suggest some other method?

Comment: Why do you want to run things in parallel to speed them up but also you're making them sleep? Why not just cycle through the objects to run the function on without using multiple threads or processes?

Comment: What I am trying to do is, send request to the URL every x sec and store that result in a file. Since there are multiple URLs, I want to run the func() in parallel. This is for monitoring purpose.

Comment: @PranitiGupta threads will work fine for that. One will be able to work while another waits for a response from the URL. In any case it doesn't sound like it's time critical so it doesn't matter if they get in each other's way a little.

Answer (score 0):

No, you needn't  limit the thread pool size be same as the number of CPU cores. If you are using it in IO high throughput situation, you could adjust your thread pool size to a suitable number which help you get the highest IO throughput, and if increasing the threads number, you couldn't get higher IO throughput number.

(I found that the maximum thread number I could set for threadpool is only around 9000, if higher, the Python3.6 reports error, and Google let me visit your question)