# Parallel Processing AWS S3 Data in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parallel-processing

I have a list of files that I need to access and process from S3 buckets through a lambda function and the idea is to loop through each of the files and collect data from all files in parallel. My first thought was to use threading which resulted in an issue that only allowed my max pool size to be 10, whereas I'm processing many files. I want to be able to continuously append processes until all files have been accessed instead of creating a list of processes and then running them in parallel which seems to be the case in multiprocessing's Pool. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to achieve performance gains [using multi-threading under a single process in python due to the GIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42541893/maximum-pool-size-when-using-threadpool-python). However you could use a bash script to start multiple python processes simultaneously.

For example if you wanted to perform some tasks and write results to a common file you could use the following prep.sh file to create an empty results file.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -e results.txt ]
then
  rm results.txt
fi
touch results.txt
```

And the following control.sh file to spawn your multiple python processes.

```
#!/bin/bash
Arr=( Do Many Things )
for i in "${Arr[@]}"; do
    python process.py $i &
done
```

With the following process.py file which simply takes a command line argument and writes it to the result file followed by a return carriage.

```
#!/bin/python
import sys

target = sys.argv[1]
def process(argument):
    with open("results.txt", "a") as results:
        results.write(argument+"\n")
process(target)
```

Ovbiously you would need to edit the array in control.sh to reflect the files you need to access and the process in process.py to reflect the retrieval and analysis of those files.